# Error message "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have added `TinyMCE` editor to add description in HTML format but when I write something in HTML and click `Add Product` It gives me this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Description="

I've tried:

1. `AllowHtml`  <= not working
2. `[HttpPost, ValidateInput(true, Exclude = "Description")]` and get this error

> System.Web.Mvc.ValidateInputAttribute' does not contain a definition for Exclude

3. `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0">` in web.config and getting this error

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

**Product.cs**

```
public partial class Product {

     public int productID {get; set;}

     [Required]
     public int Name {get; set;}

     [AllowHtml]
     public string Description {get; set;}

     public string ImagePath {get;set}
}
```

**Add Product View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Store", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data",   @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h4>Create a new product.</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@ViewBag.SizeMsg
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImagePath, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Product" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   if (file != null)
   {
      var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".JPG", ".PNG", ".JPEG" };
      if (allowedExtensions.Contains(extension))
      {
        string ImagePath = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/" + ImagePath);
        file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

        Product newRecord = new Product();
        newRecord.Name = Request.Form["Name"];
        newRecord.Description = Request.Form["Description"];
        newRecord.ImagePath = ImagePath;
        db.Products.Add(newRecord);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
      else
      {
        ViewBag.SizeMsg = "File not supported.";
        return View();
       }
   }
   return View();
 }
```

Comment: @Mormegil Please see my question, I have updated it with the solutions that I tried.

Comment: why are you applying an AllowHtml attribute to an int property? you should apply it to string properties....

Comment: @Ahmedilyas sorry, I wrote it wrong. It was `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar problems, this is the configuration I run with:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with your solution `IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error` because of this `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`

Comment: Try accessing the Form Data with:  `Request.Unvalidated.Form["MyFieldToFetch"];`

Comment: Thanks man! That worked for me. You just saved me from hittiing my head. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

add this to your config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

add add this too

```
[Post, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Operation(string Parameter) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not working, still getting the same error.

and when I added `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0">` I get this error

`HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`

Comment: for your reference http://codingstill.com/2013/01/avoiding-the-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected/

Comment: Already checked it, that didn't work. Tried `[AllowHtml]`and Tried this also `[HttpPost, ValidateInput(true, Exclude = "Description")]` but get this error `System.Web.Mvc.ValidateInputAttribute' does not contain a definition for Exclude`